# LyX natbib, referencing style

Tags: lyx, natbib

I can't get the right brackets in the PDF output of the LyX. The following figure shows the citation style selected and the latex preview of the citation.

[image]

In the output PDF I am getting big brackets instead [].

[image]

I wanted to have the citation serial number in the brackets as follows.

[image]

where 18 is the serial number. This will change depending on the position of the citation.

BTW I am using `plainnat`.

Answer (score 1):

To add this style of reference.
[image]

We need to go to Documents-> Settings-> Bibliography

Select the Natbib variant as `Author-number`.

[image]

This works fine with `plainnat`. But if you are using Springer Nature's `bst` file, you might get an error as follows:

[image]